# Prevent Android app from being associated with every file type, when sharing

Tags: android, android-manifest

In my app I have a custom file extension for saved data. I have my app showing up when a user selects this particular type of file and does "Open With".

However, it also pops up with many other unrelated file types.

The "pathPattern" seems to be ignored. Is there any way around this?

```
<!--Email attachments and browsers (no "host" - it doesn't work if there is a host)-->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <!--<data android:mimeType="*/*" />-->
    <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.customfileextension"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.customfileextension"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.customfileextension"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.customfileextension"/>
</intent-filter>

<!-- File browsers-->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.customfileextension"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.customfileextension"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.customfileextension"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.customfileextension"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Your `pathPattern`s doesn't seem right. Try to replace all the double backslashes to just ones like these:  `".*\.customfileextension"`, `".*\..*\.customfileextension"`, etc.

Comment: @Darkman thanks but that didn't work, just tried it. Also all examples of android:pathPattern I have found use double-slashes as well

Comment: What happen if you add this `<data android:mimeType="application/text/plain"/>` in your  file browsers  `intent-filter`? Change the mime type according to your needs.